# Fetch Maximum data within date range without duplicate MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, between

I had trouble in making my queries.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable AS T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id , MIN(some_timestamp)  AS some_timestamp FROM YourTable
GROUP BY user_id) AS T2
ON T1.User_Id = T2.User_Id AND T1.some_timestamp = T2.some_timestamp
WHERE Some_Timestamp BETWEEN '13-Jun-12 08:00' AND '13-Jun-12 10:00'
```

---

Table Name: YourTable

```
| PK_ID | USER_ID |  SOME_TIMESTAMP |
------------------------------------|
|     1 |     123 | 13-Jun-12 14:30 |
|     2 |     123 | 13-Jun-12 08:50 |
|     3 |     567 | 13-Jun-12 09:23 |
|     4 |     567 | 13-Jun-12 09:45 |
|     5 |     567 | 13-Jun-12 09:40 |
|     6 |     890 | 13-Jun-12 08:44 |
```

What i want to get is like this
1. Fetch Data from specific date range between [13-Jun-12 08:00] & [13-Jun-12 10:00]
2. Once it fetched the date within range, it will fetch the latest date without duplicates.

Output should be like this:
1.date range between

```
[13-Jun-12 08:00] & [13-Jun-12 10:00]
```

2. Only fetching the latest timestamp without duplicates.

Results Should be like this

```
| PK_ID | USER_ID |  SOME_TIMESTAMP |
------------------------------------|
|     2 |     123 | 13-Jun-12 08:50 |
|     4 |     567 | 13-Jun-12 09:45 |
|     6 |     890 | 13-Jun-12 08:44 |
```

Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    pk_id,
    user_id,
    MAX(some_timestamp)
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    some_timestamp>= '13-Jun-12 08:00' 
AND some_timestamp<= '13-Jun-12 10:00'
GROUP BY
    user_id
ORDER BY
    pk_id ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/627af/3)

Comment: This returns the incorrect pk_id for 567 -- it should return 4.

Comment: be careful of this approach.. this is a shortcut that will only work when all the other data is identical.. as @sgeddes pointed out, this fails here because it picks the wrong pk_id

Answer (score 1):

Your query was pretty close.  Need to select the `MAX` instead of the `MIN`, and need to move the `WHERE` criteria into the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable AS T1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id , MAX(some_timestamp)  AS some_timestamp 
   FROM YourTable
  WHERE Some_Timestamp BETWEEN '2013-06-12 08:00' AND '2013-06-12 10:00'
   GROUP BY user_id) AS T2
    ON T1.User_Id = T2.User_Id AND T1.some_timestamp = T2.some_timestamp
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53b02/2)

Returning:

```
PK_ID    USER_ID   SOME_TIMESTAMP
2        123       June, 12 2013 08:50
4        567       June, 12 2013 09:45
6        890       June, 12 2013 08:44
```

Format your `SOME_TIMESTAMP` field as needed.  I would also suggest using `>=` and `<=` instead of `BETWEEN` as you may not get your desired results with `BETWEEN`.

Comment: WHERE Some_Timestamp >= '13-Jun-12 08:00' AND some_timestamp <= '13-Jun-12 10:00'

Comment: @TigaPuluhSaat -- you got it.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want the `pk_id` at the time of the maximum timestamp.

To do this in MySQL, you would normally have to join the original data back in.  In your case, though, it seems that pk_id is increasing for increasing timestamps.  If this is true, then the following query should return what you want:

```
select max(pk_id) as pk_id, user_id, max(some_timestamp)
FROM your_table
WHERE Some_Timestamp between '13-Jun-12 08:00' AND Some_Timestamp <= '13-Jun-12 10:00'
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY pk_id ASC
```

If you do not include the `max(pk_id)`, then an arbitrary `pk_id` would be returned, and it would have nothing to do with the max timestamp.